# Unable to insert into database despite specifying a default constraint on column

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table in MySQL database:

`mysql> describe student;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name       | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dob        | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reg_no     | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| department | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| branch     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| semester   | int(11)     | YES  |     | 1       |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

When I try to insert into this database **without** specifying the last value (i.e.semester), it results in an error
`mysql> insert into student values('John Smith','1990-01-01','123ABC','Chemistry','Organic Chemistry');
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Why is this not working? Isn't that the whole point of having a default constraint? That the value specified as default gets assigned if it isn't present in the insert query.

If I write the query like this, it works:
`mysql> insert into student values('John Smith','1990-01-01','123ABC','Chemistry','Organic Chemistry',DEFAULT);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)`

What is happening? Is my syntax wrong? I would like to be able to insert the record without having to specify 'DEFAULT'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not adding values to all the table columns you should specify which columns you add data.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

So in your case,

```
INSERT INTO student(name, dob, regno, department, branch)
    VALUES ('John Smith','1990-01-01','123ABC','Chemistry','Organic Chemistry');
```

Comment: To add: I think MySQL will default to expecting values for _all_ columns if you don't specify specific columns.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong while inserting default values,so instead of that query use `insert into student(name,dob,reg_no,department,branch)values('John Smith','1990-01-01','123ABCF','Chemistry','Organic Chemistry');`